# How to remove any html like tags after typing in tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce

I have a ice inline editor where user can paste and type if required, once editing is done i am using ng-blur to save the final content to DB. My concern is user can write or paste anything which might have html like tags or even some suspicious script tags. if there is anything like suspicious code is there my code will consider it as dangerous request. So all i want to do is, on ng-blur if there are any html tags(other than ins and del), they should be removed and my editor should have clean code, so i can get that through get window[varname].getElementContent() method.

for paste, i am using following code

```
       {
           name: 'IceCopyPastePlugin',
           newLine: true,
           settings: {
              pasteType: 'formattedClean',
              preserve: '',
              afterPasteClean: function (body) {            
                 body = GetWithoutScriptString(body)
                    return body;
                 }
              }
       } ]
```

Imagine there is a div on which a inlineeditor is initialized, now i can edit the content inside that editor. I can either copypaste content or can write. All i want to do is, whenever I am making any changes inside the editor, onBlur i want to clean the content(ie remove all valid or invalid html like tags from the newly pasted or edited text

etc) of the Editor first than accept the changes and then get the correct content and save it to DB.

Now-

```
This is my original text. This is I am writing as editing with script <ins>inserted text</ins><del>deleted text</del><script>alert('xxx')</script> <div>Pratap</div><span>xxx</span>.
```

Expected -

```
This is my original text. This is I am writing as editing with script <ins>inserted text</ins><del>deleted text</del>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

***Solution Working For me:***

Client Side=>

```
var tracker =
                        new ice.InlineChangeEditor({
                            element: element[0],
                            handleEvents: true,
                            invalid_elements : 'strong,em,script,embed,style,meta,img,head,body,input,iframe,monoscript,applet,object,paramnav,a,link,videp,track,source,audio,map,frame,fieldset,label,option,select,button,textarea,form,font,b',
                            extended_valid_elements : 'span[class|data-cid|data-userid|data-username|data-time]',
                            currentUser: {
                                id: 11,
                                name: 'user'
                            },
                            plugins: [
                                {
                                    name: 'IceCopyPastePlugin',
                                    newLine: true,
                                    settings: {                                           
                                        pasteType: 'formattedClean',
                                        preserve: '',
                                        afterPasteClean: function (body) {            
                                            body = GetWithoutScriptString(body)
                                            return body;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                //, {
                                //    name: 'IcejQuerySpellcheckerPlugin',
                                //}
                            ]
                        });
```

Server Side=>

```
HtmlSanitizer sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
sanitizer.AllowedAttributes.Add("class");
sanitizer.AllowDataAttributes = true;
descHtml = sanitizer.Sanitize(descHtml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TinyMCE configuration options such as `valid_elements` / `extended_valid_elements` to control what tags you want to allow.  There are similar configuration options for controlling allowed attributes. These will help you with ensuring that TinyMCE only allows tags you want.

The configuration options that fall under this content filtering category are all documented here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/

That being said, ***you can never assume client side validation is enough to ensure your application is safe from invalid HTML, injection attacks, XSS, etc.***

The reality is nefarious people can post data to your application using other tools (CURL etc) so that the content does not go through your UI. In addition, if you misconfigure TinyMCE you might allow tags without realizing you have done so. You should always validate data **server-side** before storing it into your database - this is the only way to ensure that what you are saving is "safe".

Comment: Thank Michael Fromin, this is perfectly working for me, I choose proper setting from the given set and voila!! its working like a charm.